# Plotly Table Multiindex Dataframe

Tags: python, plotly, multi-index, plotly-python

Is there a way to create a Plotly Table from a multiindex df which preserves the merged cell labels:
[image]

Here is the code, note the numbers should be under the two columns on the right :

```
table = go.Table(
    header=dict(values=headers),
    cells=dict(values=df.T.values))

fig = go.Figure(data=table).update_layout()
fig.show()
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to accomplish what you want is to reset the index of your DataFrame so that the `NAME` and `CATEGORY` columns are no longer in the index, then replace duplicate values in the `NAME` column with a blank string `''`. Then your DataFrame will look like this (with placeholder values under `SALES`):

```
               NAME     CATEGORY  SALES DISC
0         Furniture       Tables      0  25%
1                      Bookcases      1  22%
2                         Chairs      2  17%
3                    Furnishings      3  15%
4   Office Supplies    Fasteners      4   9%
5                            Art      5   8%
6                      Envelopes      6   8%
7                          Paper      7   7%
8                        Storage      8   7%
9                       Supplies      9   7%
10                        Labels     10   6%
11                       Binders     11  39%
12                    Appliances     12  15%
```

This DataFrame is easier to pass to `go.Table` as you don't have to worry about the multiindex, yet it is formatted the same as the multiindex DataFrame.

```
df_table = df.reset_index()
df_table.loc[df_table['NAME'].duplicated(), 'NAME'] = ''

table = go.Table(
    header=dict(values=df_table.columns.tolist()),
    cells=dict(values=df_table.T.values)
    )

fig = go.Figure(data=table).update_layout()
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you , but we need the first two columns populated as well

Comment: I have updated my answer - hopefully this is more what you are looking for

Comment: Thank you. Those are impressive hacks. It is still not presentation quality - can the empty cells be merged like how Python outputs it?